# Expression Engine Continuous Integration BDD

Tags: continuous-integration, bdd, expressionengine

I am curious if anyone has setup BDD, Expression Engine and Continous integration and could share their setup/approach? I have heard rumor of people using cucumber with ee but have not see any information about this in practice.

Comment: You might want to post this to the ExpressionEngine specific StackExchange site for a faster response: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, I have added the question there as well http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/7042/expression-engine-continuous-integration-bdd